# Fazer alterações num site desenvolvido em Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Estou a iniciar o desenvolvimento em Laravel e tenho de implementar novas funcionalidades num site desenvolvido em Laravel 4.2 e por outro programador.

Preciso de criar uma função que adicione linhas a uma tabela do estilo Log, que precisa de estar acessível em todo o projeto.

```
public function logEmail( $email ){}
```

Crio um model com esta função? Como incluir o model de forma a ter esta função acessível em qualquer lado?

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A questão, neste momento, não se prende ao código em si, mas sim em relação ao funcionamento do MVC, neste caso em Laravel 4. Terei public function logEmail( $email ){ que será chamado em diversos locais do projeto. A questão é: Crio um novo model? Como "chamo" o model, de forma a aceder à função?

Comment: Rui Costa podes incluir essas dúvidas que tens na pergunta para que ela seja mais especifica. Basta clicares em [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai criar um model (Eloquent) com todas as configurações pertinentes a da tabela que reference ao seu model.

Exemplo

```
<?php
    class Log extends Eloquent 
    {
        public $table      = 'logs'; 
        public $primaryKey = 'id';
        public $timestamps = true;
        protected $fillable = array('description');

        public function getDates()
        {
            return array('created_at','updated_at');
        }
    }
```

Tendo um tabela parecida com esse layout fazendo referencia ao model Eloquent acima.

```
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`logs` 
(    
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,    
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,    
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL ,    
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Functionamento:

```
$log = Log::create(array('description' => 'info'));
```

Esse linha acima insere um registro na ***tabela de*** `logs` (não são informados os campos `created_at` e `updated_at`, porque, são gerados automáticamente).

Esse seria o funcionamento básico, aonde em qualquer **Local** você poderia chamar esse linha para criar um Log. Em modo geral você pode fazer uma linha na `BaseController` sendo a mesma responsável em gravar sempre um `Log` em todas as classes que herdaram dessa `BaseController`.

Exemplo:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

    //método padrão de LogEmail
    protected function logEmail($email)
    {
        return Log::create(array('description' => $email));
    }

}

No seu controller

<?php
    class BuscaController extends BaseController 
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();          
        }
        public function index()
        {

            $this->logEmail('email@email.com');

            return Redirect::route('index.home');

        }
    }
```

Nesse link do próprio site tem todas as [configurações do Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) e como deve ser utilizado.